# How to get name of person calling a command in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Ok so im 12 years old so sorry for any 'Stuipidness' ok so im making a discord bot and its good so far but there's one problem how do we check if someone called a command? for example:

```
@client.commands()
     async def sayname(ctx):
     await ctx.send(f'Your name is {HowToGetName}')
```

is it possibel to add two rguments like sayname(ctx, member) because i tried that and it didnt work :( Please help.

Edit: If this helps im using Python 3.8.1

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import json

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ";")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} Joined the server!')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! Server Ping: {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms.')

@client.command()
async def coinflip(ctx):
    number = random.randrange(1, 3);
    if number == 1:
        await ctx.send('Tails!')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Heads!')

@client.command()
async def test():
    await ctx.send('This is a testing command.')



client.run("Token")
```

Comment: Whats wrong why is everyone downvoting the post? i cant ask another question now :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you're looking for:

```
@client.command()
async def sayname(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Your name is {ctx.author.name}")
```

As a side not, don't post your token here. People can use that token to access your bot.

Comment: Wow that helped allot thanks also I forgot that I posted my token I will regenerate it again now thanks